# always returning english

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, nsbundle, nslocalizedstring

Here is my code:

```
    NSString *string = [bundle localizedStringForKey:@"kTCStringMissing" value:@"" table:nil];
```

I know that the bundle variable is pointing to the correct bundle because the English value is coming out correctly -- see below.

My bundle structure looks like this:

```
ToyCalculatorUI.bundle  
  en.lproj [directory]  
    Localizable.strings [file]
  de.lproj [directory]
    Localizable.strings [file]
```

My Localizable.strings look like this:

in the en.lproj directory:

kTCStringMissing = "Missing Fields en";

in the de.lproj directory:

kTCStringMissing = "Missing Fields de";

But when I run my app in the simulator, after setting the language to Deutsch, and the region to Deutschland, the *string object above always has value "Missing Fields en".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

imho you have to quote the keys, too.
(see [Apple's Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6-SW5) for details)

i.e. "kTCStringMissing" = "Missing Fields en";

Comment: The keys do have to be quoted, but you'll encounter fewer issues by using `genstrings`, Apple's supplied command-line: `genstrings -o English.lproj/ *.m`. The linked docs discuss the tool.